# How to automate opening of new tabs on Google Chrome? Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The automation task requires moving to an open tab, executing a command ( a button click) and then moving on to the next tab. This process is repeated for the next 4-5 tabs.

I already have a code that automates this process. I have a for loop that goes through each of the window handles for the opened tabs and automates the button click. But the issue is that on each tab, **the driver waits for the execution of the button click to process and the new page to load before moving on to the next tab**. I ideally want the driver to click the button and move to the next tab instantaneously without waiting for the new page to load.

Is there some method for achieving this? Are there any other options besides using Selenium for this sort of automation.

My current code looks like something like this :

```
handles = driver.window_handles
for i in range(4):
    driver.switch_to_window(handles[i])
    driver.find_element_by_id('submit').click()
```

---

```
for i in range(3):
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[i+1])

    chain = ActionChains(driver)
    element = driver.find_element_by_name('submit')
    chain.move_to_element_with_offset(element, 0, 0)
    chain.click(element)
    chain.release(element)
    chain.perform()
```

I used the aboce code to use ActionChains to click the button. But im getting a StateElementReferenceException. The rrror is triggered at chain.perform()

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: What are you doing in each tab? Are you trying to achieve "parallel" execution in a single browser or do you really need to do this?

Comment: @JeffC In each tab, Im clicking on a submit button. You could say that each submit triggers a function call and I would like these function calls to be as close to each other as possible. But yeah, its not possible for me to directly call these functions. It can only be triggered by clicking on the submit button. I wouldnt really say thats its parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

Using action chains to perform the click action will allow Selenium to continue without waiting for the result of the click action. Tested on linux, python3.4, chromedriver2.38:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

chain = ActionChains(super().driver)

try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_id('submit')
    chain.move_to_element_with_offset(element, 0, 0)
    chain.click(element)
    chain.release(element)
    # Perform the chained actions including the left-click.
    chain.perform()
except:
    print("Failed to click element")
    raise
```

Comment: This method raised a StaleElementReferenceException at chain.perform(). I have edited my question to include the code that I tried

Comment: That's odd. If the element existed at `driver.find_element_by_id('submit')`, it's a bit surprising that roughly 30ms later, it throws a StaleElementReferenceException. Are you acquiring the element on each page? Because selenium treats each element on separate pages as unique objects. That means the 'submit' button on page 1 *will not be* the same element as the 'submit' button on page 2, but it *will* recognize the object. The exception essentially is saying, "I know of this object, but it's not on this page (anymore)".